# Python lxml: Ignore XML declaration (errors)

Tags: python, xml, lxml, thunar

I am trying to parse the file browser Thunar's custom actions files (`~/.config/Thunar/uca.xml`) with the `lxml` Python module.

For some reason, Thunar obviously writes a `malformed declaration` into these files:

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>
```

Obviously, the `version` is expected to appear as the first "attribute" in the declaration. `lxml` raises an `XMLSyntaxError` if I try to parse the file.

And no, I cannot simply correct the declaration, becaue Thunar keeps overwriting it with the bogus one.

This might very likely be a bug in Thunar.

Nevertheless, **I would like to know how to ignore the XML declaration with `lxml`.**

I know that I could pre-process the XML document to filter out the XML declaration. But this doesn't seem very elegant. Since XML seems to default to version 1.0 and UTF-8 encoding, there surely is a possibility to just ignore the declaration and assume that in `lxml`. I didn't find anything in the documentation or on google, I might have overlooked something.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the complete traceback? The order of attributes is not important. It is only important if the XML document should be well-formed, which is not the same thing as valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know very little about Thunar, but if it produces the XML declaration in the question, then that is a bug. Having an incorrect XML declaration makes the document ill-formed.

The XML grammar specifies one correct order for the items in the XML declaration. `version` must come first and `encoding` second. See http://w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-XMLDecl.

However, with lxml you can parse using a parser instance that has the `recover` option set to `True`. It works in this case. The bad XML declaration is ignored.

```
from lxml import etree 

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = etree.parse('uca.xml', parser)
```

See http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html