# xml.etree giving an Invalid Token Error When Parsing PDF Metadata

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml.etree

I have a [project](https://github.com/marshalmiller/linkrot) that searches PDFs for URLs and in the process extracts the PDF Metadata. It works perfectly around 99.6% of the time without any errors. But every once in a while, a file throws the old "invalid token error. Traceback Below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
return run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python38\Scripts\linkrot.exe_main.py", line 7, in
File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\linkrot\cli.py", line 182, in main
pdf = linkrot.linkrot(args.pdf)
File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\linkrot_init.py", line 131, in init
self.reader = PDFMinerBackend(self.stream)
File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\linkrot\backends.py", line 213, in init
self.metadata.update(xmp_to_dict(metadata))
File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\linkrot\libs\xmp.py", line 92, in xmp_to_dict
return XmpParser(xmp).meta
File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\linkrot\libs\xmp.py", line 41, in init
self.tree = ET.XML(xmp)
File "c:\python38\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1320, in XML
parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 55, column 10
```

My assumption is that there is some sort of issue with the XML extracted from the PDF, but I can't be sure. Is there a workaround? Some way the rest of the program could run when this error throws? The metadata is valuable to the process so I'd like to keep it if possible. I don't know etree that well, so I'd appreciate some help. The Code itself is below:

```
class XmpParser(object):
    """
        Parses an XMP string into a dictionary.
        Usage:
            parser = XmpParser(xmpstring)
            meta = parser.meta
    """

    def __init__(self, xmp):
        self.tree = ET.XML(xmp)
        self.rdftree = self.tree.find(RDF_NS + "RDF")

    @property
    def meta(self):
        """ A dictionary of all the parsed metadata. """
        meta = defaultdict(dict)
        if self.rdftree:
            for desc in self.rdftree.findall(RDF_NS + "Description"):
                for (
                    el
                ) in (
                    desc.iter()
                ):
                    ns, tag = self._parse_tag(el)
                    value = self._parse_value(el)
                    meta[ns][tag] = value
        return dict(meta)

    def _parse_tag(self, el):
        """ Extract the namespace and tag from an element. """
        ns = None
        tag = el.tag
        if tag[0] == "{":
            ns, tag = tag[1:].split("}", 1)
            if ns in NS_MAP:
                ns = NS_MAP[ns]
        return ns, tag

    def _parse_value(self, el):  # noqa: C901
        """ Extract the metadata value from an element. """
        if el.find(RDF_NS + "Bag") is not None:
            value = []
            for li in el.findall(RDF_NS + "Bag/" + RDF_NS + "li"):
                value.append(li.text)
        elif el.find(RDF_NS + "Seq") is not None:
            value = []
            for li in el.findall(RDF_NS + "Seq/" + RDF_NS + "li"):
                value.append(li.text)
        elif el.find(RDF_NS + "Alt") is not None:
            value = {}
            for li in el.findall(RDF_NS + "Alt/" + RDF_NS + "li"):
                value[li.get(XML_NS + "lang")] = li.text
        else:
            value = el.text
        return value
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The rules of XML are strict. A "not well-formed" error is serious. Apparently the metadata for some PDF file is corrupt. This question does not contain any new information compared to  https://stackoverflow.com/q/73188236/407651.

Comment: You could try wrapping `self.tree = ET.XML(xmp)` in a `try/except` block to handle the rare cases where the metadata cannot be parsed as XML.

Comment: Sorry. I do have new information. Essentially, the metadata extracts fine from every file. It throws this error for files with metadata starting with a number, which is a no-no. 

What I am looking to do is pass an argument to the XML parser library to ignore invalid tags and drop them.

Comment: "files with metadata starting with a number" - What does that mean? Anyway, ElementTree does not have any argument to ignore invalid tags. But the lxml library does have a `recover` option. Maybe you can try that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367355/407651

Comment: Some files contain metadata with a tag that starts with a number. An XML tag cannot start with a number. It's invalid. But since it's pulling it from a PDF, there is no way for me to change it manually. Let me look into lxml. That sounds promising. Thanks.